# How to add REST basic authentication to existing XML Spring Security config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working with Spring Security 4 XML based configuration.

This is my configuration (`security.xml`):

```xml
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http create-session="always" 
        use-expressions="true" 
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" 
        entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <logout />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my `CustomEntryPoint`:

```java
@Component
public class CustomEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Entering commence due to failed Authentication");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized Access!");
    }

}
```

and my `UserDao` (for future reading credentials from file):

```java
public class UserDao implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        String password = readPasswordFromFileOrDatabase(username);

        if (password == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("failure");
        return User.withUsername("user").password(password).authorities("ROLE_USER").build();
    }

    private String readPasswordFromFileOrDatabase(String username) {
        if (username.equals("user")) return "q";
        return null;
    }


}
```

And it looks like REST feauture doesn't work, when I send `POST` through Postman to `http://localhost:8080/login` with user/password: user/q it says

> Bad credentials

But when I do the same thing through form in browser it works fine.

So, is there any way to make REST features work?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will give you base64 encoded value of username and password. Use that to add a HTTP header as following:

```
String plainClientCredentials="myusername:mypassword";
String base64ClientCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainClientCredentials.getBytes()));
System.out.println(base64ClientCredentials);`
```

In headers set this:

*Key- Authorization, Value-Basicbase64ClientCredentials*

Suppose the code prints `123&78#`
then value would be `Basic123&78#`.

Comment: not sure if it works, because after adding header I got the same behavior